# Cannot display rows correct in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid where i display Columns dynamically and rows depending on the columns .

My question regards the rows that should be displayed, if I in my controller class wrote a inner class:

```
public class MeetingClass
{
    public MeetingClass()
    {
        Data = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    }

    public string records { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public string SortColumn { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller have the following:

```
var jsonData = new MeetingClass
                {
                    records = "",
                    total = cbrUsers.Count,
                    Page = page,
                    PageSize = rows,
                    SortColumn = sidx
                };

cbrUsers.ForEach(x =>
{
    var item = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    jsonData.Data.Add(item);
    int counter = 1;
    item.Add("Deltagare", x.FullName);
    meeting.SecondOpinionGroup.OrderBy(y => y.SecondOpinionGroupId).ForEach(z =>
    {
        item.Add("Grupp" + counter, "false");
        counter++;
    });

    item.Add("Ta_bort", "Ta bort deltagare");
});

return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

It works perfectly. I tried to write my controller in a different style and skip the inner class With the following:

```
var jsonData = new
                {
                    records = "",
                    total = cbrUsers.Count,
                    Page = page,
                    PageSize = rows,
                    SortColumn = sidx,
                    Data = new List<string>()

                };

cbrUsers.ForEach(x =>
{
    int counter = 1;
    var item = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    item.Add("Deltagare", x.FullName);
    meeting.SecondOpinionGroup.OrderBy(y => y.SecondOpinionGroupId).ForEach(z =>
    {
        item.Add("Grupp" + counter, "false");
        counter++;
    });
    item.Add("Ta_bort", "Ta bort deltagare");
    jsonData.Data.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));

});
```

I dont get any error but my jqgrid is empty in the rows, how come `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` doesnt work but the attribute `[JsonExtensionData]` works?

Best Regards Erik

Comment: jqGrid is pure **JavaScript** library implemented as jQuery plugin. You should include JavaScript code, which you use to create jqGrid. Moreover it's important to know which version of ASP.NET MVC, which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Typically one shoule **never call** `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` explicitly. ASP.NET MVC will serialize the object for you (in `Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`).

Comment: It's unclear from your code, whether you implemented (or want to implement) **server side** paging and sorting. jqGrid allows to use `loadonce: true` option (and `forceClientSorting: true` additionally in free jqGrid). It allows to return *all data at once* from the controller action. jqGrid will implement sorting, paging and filtering functionality for you on the client side. It's clear that one should have not so large total number of rows in the case (<1000 or <10000 for example). [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) displays 4000 rows.